# How to limit <apex:textArea> length?

Tags: visualforce

I am having trouble with data type Text Area(255), as there is no limit of character length.

I am having 1 field, Next_Step__c which is of data type Text Area.

I am showing it in VF page:

```
<apex:inputTextArea value="{!account.Next_Steps__c}"  cols="60" rows="3" />
```

But, problem is there there is no max Length.

so is there any solution to achieve this : Max length I need 255 character.?

Comment: TextArea(255) that means it should take 255 character. But in text Area you can enter as many as character you want.

For example : we can enter as many as character. but I want it to limit max. 255 character.

Comment: Please see my answer, I deleted my comment cause it made no sense

Comment: http://www.forcetree.com/2013/02/character-count-limit-for-inputtextarea.html

Answer (score 4):

A `maxlength` attribute for `textarea` is a recent innovation in browsers and support is missing from IE9 and others (see e.g. [HTML  maxlength Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)). So at present Visualforce doesn't offer a solution.

So if you want to enforce this on the client side e.g. to stop accepting characters after 255 have been typed in (or pasted in) then to work in a wide range of browsers you will need to use JavaScript. But AFAIK there isn't one "perfect" solution, but rather a variety of suggestions - see e.g. [How can I block further input in textarea using maxlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578678/how-can-i-block-further-input-in-textarea-using-maxlength).

To avoid JavaScript you can check the length at the server and output a message if the text is too long. Or you could just silently truncate to 255 characters at the server...

Comment: is there any way to truncate to 255 character ?

1 way I found : s = s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), 255));

Comment: @Rudra_NoVoice Yours is neater than mine; I'd usually use something like `s = s.length() > max ? s.substring(0, max) : s;`.

Comment: Can you please give a little light on how to use HTML text area on Visual force page?

Comment: @SFDCGeek Like all Visualforce an `apex:inputTextArea` emits HTML tags and it is a `textarea` in that case. You can mix the Visualforce tags and raw HTML tags but generally it is cleaner not to. When adding JavaScript such as jQuery JavaScript the context is the HTML tags not the Visualforce ones sp the HTML documentation is worth looking at. Not sure if this answers you question or not...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know if I understand the question but Text Area(255) is the largest number of characters that can be counted with an 8-bit number..

Are you trying to limit the length of what users are aloud to input? So only be 5 characters for instance?  If this is the case you should be able to create a validation rule on  `Next_Step__c` such as LEN(Next_Steps__c) > 5 (whatever it is)

Edit
You can also try `maxlength` **Keith beat me to it

This also may help you
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm

Comment: can we trim the length of the text area before make it operational? (In case I don't want to use Validation)

Comment: Oh I see, I believe Keith has a better solution then

Comment: Do you know how to use HTMl text area in VF page?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would seem to be using  and having that point to a Text Area field. That would get the length limited to whatever the limit is in Salesforce. I don't know how you would make the text box be a certain width, though - anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

The `<apex:inputtexarea>` is one of the Visualforce components that support the use of [HTML pass-through](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm).  If the issue is how to use the maxlength attribute, then pass the attribute through using html as a prefix like:

```
<apex:inputTextArea value="{!account.Next_Steps__c}"  cols="60" rows="3" html-maxlength="10" />
```

I wrote about this in a blog post: http://forceforte.com/limit-character-count-for-apex-inputtextarea-in-visualforce-using-angularjs/

Comment: This is my first time of using StackExchange so the code I wanted to add is here below: < apex:inputTextArea value="{!account.Next_Steps__c}"  cols="60" rows="3" html-maxlength="10" />

Comment: I edited it for you. All you need to do is highlight the code block you want to format, and click the curly bracket button on the rich text editor, or ctrl + k

Comment: I'm recommending this answer for deletion because one of its primary purposes is to promote the linked blog post, which you own but have not disclosed.