# html-maxlength attribute is not working for apex:inputtextarea with rich text enabled

Tags: visualforce, richtextarea

Below is my vf page line

```
<apex:inputtextarea html-maxlength="500" richText="true" styleClass="inputRichText"  id="inputRichText" value="{!some_Field__c}" />
```

html-maxlength is not working here, I mean text area excepting more than 500 characters. I guess html-maxlength attribute with richtext is not supported. Do we have any other options?

Comment: You can refer these links - 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/how-to-limit-apextextarea-length
https://forceforte.com/limit-character-count-for-apex-inputtextarea-in-visualforce-using-angularjs/

Comment: The html-maxlength works fine with just apex:inputTextArea, setting richText="true" seems to be the issue.